# "Copy" the public object properties to a local object

Tags: vb.net

How can a local object to adopt the publicly declared object's (ex. DropDownList) properties? I'll be using *this* method since I will have a lot of local `dropdownlist` objects in the `Partial Class`.

```
Public Class connection

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Connections
    Public cn As New SqlConnection
    Public cmd As SqlCommand
    Public rs As SqlDataReader
    Public dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Public ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

       'Public Objects
    Public ddlAcadyr As DropDownList = New DropDownList()

 Public Sub AcadYr()
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT AcadYr FROM TermSchedule", cn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        adp.Fill(ds)
        ddlAcadyr.DataSource = ds
        ddlAcadyr.DataTextField = "AcadYr"
        ddlAcadyr.DataBind()
        ddlAcadyr.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
        ddlAcadyr.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

End Class

Partial Class Home
    Inherits connection

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call AcadYr()
        ddlPrivateAcadyr = ddlAcadyr '*NOTE: ddlPrivateAcadyr is a private object dropdownlist in class home
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `connection class` you can use a `Shared Sub` like this:

```
Public Sub SetAcadYrProperties(ByVal ddlAcadYrToCustomize as DropDownList)

    Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT AcadYr FROM TermSchedule", cn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adp.Fill(ds)
    ddlAcadYrToCustomize.DataSource = ds
    ddlAcadYrToCustomize.DataTextField = "AcadYr"
    ddlAcadYrToCustomize.DataBind()
    ddlAcadYrToCustomize.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
    ddlAcadYrToCustomize.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub
```

And call it from `Home class` like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SetAcadYrProperties(ddlPrivateAcadyr)
End Sub
```

If this solutions works you can delete `ddlAcadyr` and `AcadYr()` in `connection class`.